# Find inverse matrix to row-reduced echelon

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&3&2&0 \\ 2&0&4&-3\\ 1 & -1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

$R = PA$

$R$ is the canonical form similar to $A$. Find $P$.

I wasn't sure how I could find $P$. maybe I could use row operations on $A$ to get a row-reduced echelon and then to make the same row operations on $I_{3x3}$ ?

Comment: If by “canonical form” you mean row-reduced echelon form, then yes, that will work.

Comment: @amd yes row-reduced echelon form is what I ment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you apply the same row operations to the identity matrix, you will end up with $P$.

To see why this is so, consider the augmented matrix $[A\,|\,I]$. If you left-multiply this by a product $P$ of elementary matrices you get $[R\,|\,P]$, but this is equivalent to performing the corresponding row operations on the augmented matrix.